# Obtaining data from server for POST not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

I am still quite new to Jquery and Ajax request. On the website I am developing I have a simply form element that sends the input data which is an email to the server. For some reason I cant find a way to obtain the form information to send it to the server.

Here is my Jquery code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var temp = "http://localhost:5000/"
  $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
var aa = $('#target').serialize();
alert( "Handler for .submit() called." + aa);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: temp+"sign",
  data: aa,
  success: function(){},
  dataType: "string"
    });
  });
});
```

it is quite messy... I am trying to diagnose the problem.

this is the form element

```
<form class="form-inline text-center-min" id="target" style="padding-bottom: 100px">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control filter" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-filter">Join</button>
</form>
```

Please it would be awesome for any help for this.

Comment: I suspect you are missing the `event.preventDefault()` inside the `submit` event handler and the page gets reloaded when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Use event.preventDefault(); head of your callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var temp = "http://localhost:5000/"
    $("#target").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var aa = $('#target').serialize();
        alert("Handler for .submit() called." + aa);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: temp + "sign",
            data: aa,
            success: function () {},
            dataType: "string"
        });
    }); });
```

Comment: I tryed that but when I submited the form on the server end I am just console logging the email and its logging out undefined

Comment: Can not say anything without seeing. How are you doing console logging?

Comment: on my server this is what I am seeing...                          Node app is running at localhost:5000
undefined
undefined
undefined and the code for the node server is                            
app.post('/sign', function(request, response) {
  console.log(request.body);
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'));
});

Comment: Because your input doesn't have name attribute. Assign name attribute and use this on server side.